# How can I set a fake location on iOS to be used by all apps?

Tags: ios, swift, location, cllocationmanager

I am wanting to write a personal "fake location" iOS app that could toggle between a fake location and true location for other apps on my device without having to tether to the Xcode Simulator. [This](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2014/03/19/simulator-enhancements.html) article seems to suggest that this is possible by "swizzling" a fake location into Apple's CLLocationManager class to be used by other apps, but I am unfamiliar with the Objective-C code (more familiar with Swift). Does anyone know if swizzling in such a way in an app is possible and would affect location in other apps? If so, any suggestions on how to swizzle this in Swift? If not, is there any other way to set a fake location within one app's code that would affect other apps' location data?

Thank you.

Comment: Swizzling will only affect your code/app

Answer (score 1):

Assuming we're talking a non-jailbroken iOS device, there's pretty much no way an app can in any way "fake" a current location. There's a very outside chance that there may be some private framework methods that could let you hack something, but attempting to do so would result in an instant rejection if you tried to submit such an app to the App Store.